# mod_rewrite nested directory to dynamic page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a heck of a time getting this one to work.
I have a directory structure:

```
/province/city/business_name.php
```

I want to rewrite this so that the URL is preserved but it loads this page for dynamic content:

```
/listing.php?p=province&c=city&b=business
```

How the heck do I do this in mod_rewrite? There seem to be lots of solutions but none of them have worked for me.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

Try this solution

First, check if all variables is not empty, and after this, try to check if path is correct and file exist. If is right, you can include file.

```
<?php    
        $province = $_GET['p'];
        $city = $_GET['c'];
        $business = $_GET['b'];

        if($province && $city && $business){
            if(file_exists('/'.$province.'/'.$city.'/'.$business.'.php')){
                include_once('/'.$province.'/'.$city.'/'.$business.'.php')
            }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Finally got it!

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).php /listing.php?p=$1&c=$2&b=$3 [NC]
```

Works perfectly.